# How can I fix the "Cannot find module 'bplist-parser'" error with PhoneGap?

Tags: phone, nodejs

I've installed everything - node.js and then used `npm` to get PhoneGap.

But then I get this error when I start PhoneGap:

```
phonegap
```

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'bplist-parser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigChanges/ConfigFile.js:20:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply update the dependencies with `npm`:

```
sudo npm update -g
```

and it will launch:

```
phonegap
```

```
Usage: phonegap [options] [commands]

Description:

  PhoneGap command-line tool.

Commands:

  help [command]       output usage information
  create <path>        create a phonegap project
  build <platforms>    build the project for a specific platform
  install <platforms>  install the project on for a specific platform
  run <platforms>      build and install the project for a specific platform
  platform [command]   update a platform version
  plugin [command]     add, remove, and list plugins
  template [command]   list available app templates
  ...
```

<sup>[Source](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-cannot-find-module-bplist-parser/38551/4)</sup>

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: I had this problem with Cordova. And the solution proposed for PhoneGap can be used for Cordova too. (It worked for me and I'm using Cordova.)